# Insert into view

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

In Oracle I create a view using a 'union all' as below

```
create view TESTVIEW as 
select column1 from TABLE1 
union all 
select column1 from TABLE2;
```

If I want to insert into this view I get

SQL Error: ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view

Is there any way around this if I know I want to insert in TABLE1?

Comment: This view is not updatable, you have to insert directly into table1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to create an **INSTEAD OF INSERT** trigger on the view.

You'll need to write the trigger to insert the row in the base table, and it will run "instead of" the original insert.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/view-updatability.html to understand which views are directly updatable. For views which are not directly updatable use "Instead of" trigger as suggested in the above post.